# How to export lru_cache in python?

Tags: python, save, memoization, lru

I'm using the decorator `@lru_cache(maxsize=None)` from `functools`, and I wan't to save the memoized values to a file in order to avoid re-computing them each time I run the code.

Is there an elegant way of doing this different from printing args and values to a file and then reading them?

Comment: `functools.lru_cache()` is designed to work with arbitrary positional and keyword arguments, and possibly a maximum cache size.  If you don't need those features, it isn't too difficult to roll your own cache (aka memoize) decorator.  The cache is just a dictionary, so you can provide a function to save it to disk as a pickle (or json if you want to be able to look at it) and reload it later.  The lru_cache sourcecode is also [available](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/functools.py); modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: @RootTwo Could you add this comment as an answer? This is indeed the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Carlos Pinzón, posted as an answer as you requested: functools.lru_cache() is designed to work with arbitrary positional and keyword arguments, and possibly a maximum cache size. If you don't need those features, it isn't too difficult to roll your own cache (aka memoize) decorator. The cache is just a dictionary, so you can provide a function to save it to disk as a pickle (or json if you want to be able to look at it) and reload it later. The lru_cache sourcecode is also available; modify it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, I think the only way to do this is to get information for the .cache_info() function and to write into file.

It would a CacheInfo object that contains information you need.

Comment: The _CacheInfo object only stores the cache statistics: hits, misses, max size, and current size.  Nothing that would let you save and restore the cache.